# ember server out of memory

Tags: node.js, ember.js

Lastly, I use ember to develop. But I found it strange that when I installs packages like the following order: `npm install` and then `bower install`, it caused the out of memory exception; and when I exchange the order, it works well.
The exception is as follows:

```
WARNING: Node v8.1.2 has currently not been tested against Ember CLI and may result in unexpected behaviour.

<--- Last few GCs --->

[5015:0x102805200]    74556 ms: Mark-sweep 1404.9 (1464.9) -> 1404.8 (1439.9) MB, 2781.4 / 0.0 ms  (+ 0.0 ms in 0 steps since start of marking, biggest step 0.0 ms, walltime since start of marking 2781 ms) last resort
[5015:0x102805200]    77514 ms: Mark-sweep 1404.8 (1439.9) -> 1404.8 (1439.9) MB, 2957.7 / 0.0 ms  last resort


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x10d601fa9891 <JS Object>
    3: keysForTree [/Users/gpc/Documents/codes/gitlab/sixtant-fornt/sixtant/node_modules/.0.3.1@broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:36] [bytecode=0x15fbb22b08a9 offset=63](this=0x2a2411a8b051 <JS Global Object>,fullPath=0x1e708a1f0629 <String[860]: /Users/gpc/Documents/codes/gitlab/sixtant-fornt/sixtant/node_modules/.6.0.0@broccoli-babel-transpiler/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Factory::NewScopeInfo(int) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::ScopeInfo::Create(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Zone*, v8::internal::Scope*, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::ScopeInfo>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::Scope::AllocateScopeInfosRecursively(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::ScopeInfo>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::DeclarationScope::AllocateVariables(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::AnalyzeMode) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::DeclarationScope::Analyze(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::AnalyzeMode) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::Compiler::Analyze(v8::internal::ParseInfo*, v8::internal::ThreadedList<v8::internal::ThreadedListZoneEntry<v8::internal::FunctionLiteral*> >*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetOptimizedCode(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ConcurrencyMode, v8::internal::BailoutId, v8::internal::JavaScriptFrame*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Compiler::CompileOptimized(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ConcurrencyMode) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: v8::internal::Runtime_CompileOptimized_Concurrent(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x253ed080437d
[1]    5015 abort      ember s
```

And the node version is v8.1.2, npm version is 5.0.3.

By the way, when the node version is v5.5.0, the exception is as follows:
[image]

Here is the `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sixtant",
  "dependencies": {
    "ember": "~2.6.0",
    "ember-cli-shims": "0.1.1",
    "ember-cli-test-loader": "0.2.2",
    "ember-load-initializers": "ember-cli/ember-load-initializers#0.1.4",
    "ember-qunit": "^0.4.9",
    "ember-qunit-notifications": "^0.1.0",
    "ember-resolver": "~0.1.18",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "loader.js": "ember-cli/loader.js#3.2.1",
    "qunit": "~1.17.1",
    "fastclick": "~1.0.6",
    "lodash": "^2.4.0"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "ember": "~2.6.0"
  }
}
```

And the `package.json` is :

```
{
  "name": "sixtant",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Small description for sixtant goes here",
  "private": true,
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build -o build --environment production",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember test"
  },
  "repository": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.10.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.4",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
    "ember-cli": "2.6.3",
    "ember-cli-app-version": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.6",
    "ember-cli-dependency-checker": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-cli-fastclick": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars": "^1.0.3",
    "ember-cli-htmlbars-inline-precompile": "^0.3.1",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-jshint": "^1.0.0",
    "ember-cli-qunit": "^1.4.0",
    "ember-cli-release": "^0.2.9",
    "ember-cli-sass": "^6.1.1",
    "ember-cli-sri": "^2.1.0",
    "ember-cli-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "ember-data": "^2.6.0",
    "ember-export-application-global": "^1.0.5",
    "ember-load-initializers": "^0.5.1",
    "ember-resolver": "^2.0.3",
    "liquid-fire": "^0.27.0",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.1",
    "sass": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

So why? Is bower and npm independent? Why the OOM happens?

Comment: Could you try to delete your whole node_modules directory and try yarn instead? If it is still causing trouble: what operating and file system do you use? EDIT: it would also help if you could provide the bower.json and package.json.

Comment: @Timm, the os is Mac OS X 10.10.5，and file system is hfs. I haven't tried yarn yet. I will try it later. And `package.json` and `bower.json` are added above.

Comment: I'm running into this problem when building for production on a gitlab shared ci environment with prember and fastboot